# WPF ComboBox history - Looking for implementation suggestion

Tags: wpf, combobox

Im looking forward to writing a combobox with history. Much like address bar, only simpler(no searching, use history only). Since this is quite common, i think maybe there is a library or anything on it. I dont want to write the system from scratch(which ive been doing anyway until i realize its too much work for simple unrequired feature).

So, my question is, how can i have a combobox that can save information that user entered, manage the information that the user entered(delete, rank up/down etc).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think one solution could be to define an object with hold the entered information and other information like delete command, rank value. then put this object in a observablecollection, use it as the combobox itemsource and whenever a user put something in your comboxbox update your collection in the way you want.

Comment: thats what ive been thinking. i guess there is no simple solution. thanks.